# Where did my flag options go?

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions, deleted-questions

As I recall I used to have more flagging options than this. Did something change?  Is this just because of my low rep? Or a recent declined flag?

> [image]

Comment: Maybe the question is already closed?

Comment: Yeah just refreshed the page and it was on hold. Thanks.

Comment: And just random info; had you been blocked from flagging, you wouldn't have seen the options you did. (Or definitely not the "other" option...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to flag a post that has already been closed or deleted by the time you clicked the 'flag' link.

The dialog is loaded with AJAX when you click the link and its contents depend on the *current* state of the question, not on what the state was when you first loaded the page.

Reload the page; it most likely has already been handled.